# Did I do the inverse of this quadratic function in the correct way?

Tags: inverse-function

$$n(t)=17t^2-20t+700$$
$$y=n(t)$$
$$y=17t^2-20t+700$$
Switching $y$ and $t$,
$$t=17y^2-20y+700$$
$$t=(17y^2-20y)+700   -(Eq. 1)$$
Completion of squares:
$$\mathbf a=\sqrt{17}y$$
$$\mathbf b=???$$
$$\mathbf 2ab=-20y$$
$$\mathbf b=\frac{-20y}{2\sqrt{17}y}$$
$$\therefore b=\frac{-10}{\sqrt{17}}$$
$$\therefore(\sqrt{17}y-\frac{10}{\sqrt{17}})^2=17y^2-20y+\frac{100}{17}$$
Therefore add and subtract $b^2$ i.e., $\frac{100}{17}$ in $Eq. 1$:
$$t=(17y^2-20y+\frac{100}{17})+700-\frac{100}{17}$$
$$\therefore t=(\sqrt{17}y-\frac{10}{\sqrt{17}})^2+\frac{11800}{17}$$
$$\therefore \pm\sqrt{t-\frac{11800}{17}}=\sqrt{17}y-\frac{10}{\sqrt{17}}$$
$$\therefore y=\frac{\frac{10}{\sqrt{17}}\pm\sqrt{t-\frac{11800}{17}}}{\sqrt{17}}$$
$$\therefore n^{-1}(t)=\frac{\frac{10}{\sqrt{17}}\pm\sqrt{t-\frac{11800}{17}}}{\sqrt{17}}$$
Is my approach and answer correct? And also, I feel completion of squares a little vulnerable to errors. How could have I solved the same without completion of squares?

Comment: Basic approach is fine. Switching $y,t$ is somewhat confusing. Minor error towards end: $700-\frac{100}{17}=\frac{11800}{17}$ not $\frac{1180}{17}$.

Comment: Edited the error. Thanks. And generally switching $y,t$ is just confusing or we shouldn't switch like that?